# Properly display utf-8 HTML characters in non-multibyte Vim

Tags: html, vim, utf-8

I've been attempting to open .epub files in vim for reading (yes it's silly, let's ignore that for now) and I'm having trouble with how the internal html of epubs displays characters such as ' and " among other things.

Vim displays `'` as `â~@~Y` while opening the file with less gives me `<E2><80><99>`. I'm not sure how vim deals with this (it seems to treat `~@` and `~Y` as single characters) and as such I'm not sure how to go about replacing the special HTML characters with their utf-8 equivalent.

Is there a encoding setting that will display this properly? Or a way to manually input these characters such that I could create a search and replace macro?

Thanks

Comment: These are not HTML entities: they are most likely to be the result of a bad encoding detection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like Vim doesn't properly detect the UTF-8 encoding; you can check with

```
:setlocal fileencoding?
```

and force UTF-8 with

```
:edit ++enc=utf-8 file.epub
```

(or tweak your `'fileencodings'` option to have it automatically detected).

Comment: seems like my version isn't compiled with the +multi_byte option, any other options?

Comment: No, you have to find a Vim with multi-byte support, or live with the strange representations, or find an _utf82ascii_ utility that first converts the file to ASCII. Or, if you can live with the `<xx>` representation that less gives you, open the file in binary mode with `vim -b`.